# Can't properly log out using Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When I log out of my app using Cognito, there is still a Cognito cookie that stays and auto logins the user for an hour. It doesn't even go to the hosted UI screen to choose users, just automatically logs in whenever the authority log in link is visited.

Is there any way to properly log out?

Comment: See [revoking tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-revocation.html).

Comment: Revoking tokens does not get rid of the cognito cookie that can log a user back in automatically @jarmod